# How to stop speaking in multithreading?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a form that is displaying a message box and at the same time started a new thread that speaks the same message.

What I want to achieve is to stop the thread speaking the message as soon as I click `OK` button on the message box.

I have tried killing the thread using the abort command as soon as I click `OK` on the message box but the SPEAK process still keeps speaking the whole message even the message box goes away.

I assume that the new thread is being killed by the abort command but the speak process might be using some player to speak the message and that player is not being stopped. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
Imports SpeechLib

Public Class Form1


    Public voice As SpVoice = New SpVoice()
    Public speak As Boolean = True

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click

        Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf THREAD)
        t1.IsBackground = True
        t1.Start()
        MessageBox.Show("Data has not been saved yet. Are you sure you want to quit with out saving the chandes?")
        t1.Abort()

    End Sub

    Public Sub THREAD()

        If (speak = True) Then

            voice.Speak("Data has not been saved yet. Are you sure you want to quit with out saving the chandes?")

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should start an **asynchronous** speech by specifying:

```
SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync
```

Then you could stop the speech using **Skip**:

```
voice.Skip("Sentence", Int32.MaxValue)
```

This gives:

```
Imports SpeechLib

Public Class Form1


    Public voice As SpVoice = New SpVoice()
    Public speak As Boolean = True

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click

        Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf THREAD)
        t1.IsBackground = True
        t1.Start()
        MessageBox.Show("Data has not been saved yet. Are you sure you want to quit with out saving the chandes?")
                    voice.Skip("Sentence", Int32.MaxValue)

    End Sub

    Public Sub THREAD()

        If (speak = True) Then

            voice.Speak("Data has not been saved yet. Are you sure you want to quit with out saving the chandes?", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync)

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution work is fine. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have another question. I want to achieve a form explode effect.

Comment: The form should display at the minimum size possible to 800 by 600 pixels. I m using the following code its not showing the way i want to do to show

Answer (score -1):

you can abort thread by calling

```
t1.Abort()
```

Comment: It is already present in my code. Abort command does not stop the voice speaking the whole message. I need a command to stop the voice as soon as i click on the OK button on the message box.